# Bathtub won’t drain

Tags: drain

The tub was draining perfectly until I pulled a little hair from the drain. Now the bucket system in my very old tub, wont stay down. I pulled it, soaked it in CLR and greased it but now the lever won’t stay down.The drain won’t drain. It’s like I pulled something shut or I don’t understand what. I’ve snaked it with no hair or residue of any kind. Drain cleaner was used days before I tried CLR down that drain.I couldn’t find another bucket that would be the right size. Help.

Comment: It's really hard to help you with such limited information.  I'm going to take a stab and refer you to this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drbcDvbzh-E